# Pandas - Combine two rows into a single row and create new columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame that has 5 columns and thousands rows. I am trying to merge two specific rows into one single row based on datetime, Mac, Source and Association (one associated with one disassociated).... the data frame is like this

The dataframe is sorted, like that

```
df.sort_values(['datetime', 'Association'],ascending=[True,False])
```

| id | datetime | Mac | Source | Association |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32310 | 2023-06-07 07:39:48 | 00:00:00:00:00:1e | B1-31 | associated |
| 36653 | 2023-06-07 07:40:02 | 00:00:00:00:00:1e | B1-31 | disassociated |
| 32313 | 2023-06-07 07:40:02 | 00:00:00:00:00:1e | B2-21 | associated |
| 32358 | 2023-06-07 07:40:19 | 00:00:00:00:00:1e | B2-21 | disassociated |
| 32341 | 2023-06-07 07:40:26 | 00:00:00:00:00:1e | PI-12 | disassociated |
| 37577 | 2023-06-07 07:40:26 | 00:00:00:00:00:1e | PS-19 | associated |
| 32955 | 2023-06-07 07:40:31 | 00:00:00:00:00:1e | PS-19 | disassociated |
| 32364 | 2023-06-07 07:40:31 | 00:00:00:00:00:1f | B2-21 | associated |
| 32046 | 2023-06-07 07:41:04 | 00:00:00:00:00:1f | B2-21 | disassociated |
| 32405 | 2023-06-07 07:41:04 | 00:00:00:00:00:1f | B1-31 | associated |
| 32431 | 2023-06-07 07:41:14 | 00:00:00:00:00:1f | B1-31 | disassociated |
| 33915 | 2023-06-07 07:41:14 | 00:00:00:00:00:1f | B3-24 | associated |
| 32458 | 2023-06-07 07:41:33 | 00:00:00:00:00:1f | B3-24 | disassociated |

What I want the output as

| id | datetime associated | datetime disassociated | Mac | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-07 07:39:48 | 2023-06-07 07:40:02 | 00:00:00:00:00:1e | B1-31 |
| 2 | 2023-06-07 07:40:02 | 2023-06-07 07:40:19 | 00:00:00:00:00:1e | B2-21 |
| 3 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2023-06-07 07:40:26 | 00:00:00:00:00:1e | PI-12 |
| 4 | 2023-06-07 07:40:26 | 2023-06-07 07:40:31 | 00:00:00:00:00:1e | PS-19 |
| 5 | 2023-06-07 07:40:31 | 2023-06-07 07:41:04 | 00:00:00:00:00:1f | B2-21 |
| 6 | 2023-06-07 07:41:04 | 2023-06-07 07:41:14 | 00:00:00:00:00:1f | B1-31 |
| 7 | 2023-06-07 07:41:14 | 2023-06-07 07:41:33 | 00:00:00:00:00:1f | B3-24 |

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a continuation of spinodal's solution:

```
df2 = df.pivot(
    index=["Mac", "Source"],
    columns="Association",
    values="datetime",
).reset_index()

df2.columns.name = None

df2 = df2.rename(
    columns={
        "associated": "datetime associated",
        "disassociated": "datetime disassociated",
    }
)

df2['datetime associated'] = df2['datetime associated'].astype('datetime64')
df2['datetime disassociated'] = df2['datetime disassociated'].astype('datetime64')

df2 = df2[['datetime associated', 'datetime disassociated', 'Mac', 'Source']]
```

Comment: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: Change the pivot to pivot_table and add `aggfunc = lambda x: x` to the arguments.

Comment: Works, but datetime records are multiplied when there are multiple records with same mac and source

Comment: Without the lambda function it was exactly as I needed it... Repeat the correct answer for approval... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This output needs a bit more processing but accomplishes the hard part of reshaping the data:
`df.pivot(index=['Source', 'Mac'], columns=['Association'], values=['datetime'])`

```
        datetime
        Association         associated          disassociated
Source  Mac     
B1-31   00:00:00:00:00:1e   2023-06-14 07:39:48 2023-06-14 07:40:02
        00:00:00:00:00:1f   2023-06-14 07:41:04 2023-06-14 07:41:14
B2-21   00:00:00:00:00:1e   2023-06-14 07:40:02 2023-06-14 07:40:19
        00:00:00:00:00:1f   2023-06-14 07:40:31 2023-06-14 07:41:04
B3-24   00:00:00:00:00:1f   2023-06-14 07:41:14 2023-06-14 07:41:33
PI-12   00:00:00:00:00:1e   NaT                 2023-06-14 07:40:26
PS-19   00:00:00:00:00:1e   2023-06-14 07:40:26 2023-06-14 07:40:31
```

Comment: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Answer (score 0):

[Pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) is the way to go:

`df = data.pivot(index=('Mac', 'Source'), columns='Association', values='datetime').reset_index()`

Comment: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach you could try :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [32310, 36653, 32313, 32358, 32341, 37577, 32955, 32364, 32046, 32405, 32431, 33915, 32458],
    'datetime': ['2023-06-07 07:39:48', '2023-06-07 07:40:02', '2023-06-07 07:40:02', '2023-06-07 07:40:19',
                 '2023-06-07 07:40:26', '2023-06-07 07:40:26', '2023-06-07 07:40:31', '2023-06-07 07:40:31',
                 '2023-06-07 07:41:04', '2023-06-07 07:41:04', '2023-06-07 07:41:14', '2023-06-07 07:41:14',
                 '2023-06-07 07:41:33'],
    'Mac': ['00:00:00:00:00:1e', '00:00:00:00:00:1e', '00:00:00:00:00:1e', '00:00:00:00:00:1e',
            '00:00:00:00:00:1e', '00:00:00:00:00:1e', '00:00:00:00:00:1e', '00:00:00:00:00:1f',
            '00:00:00:00:00:1f', '00:00:00:00:00:1f', '00:00:00:00:00:1f', '00:00:00:00:00:1f',
            '00:00:00:00:00:1f'],
    'Source': ['B1-31', 'B1-31', 'B2-21', 'B2-21', 'PI-12', 'PS-19', 'PS-19', 'B2-21', 'B2-21',
               'B1-31', 'B1-31', 'B3-24', 'B3-24'],
    'Association': ['associated', 'disassociated', 'associated', 'disassociated', 'disassociated',
                    'associated', 'disassociated', 'associated', 'disassociated', 'associated',
                    'disassociated', 'associated', 'disassociated']
})


# Sort the dataframe by datetime and Association
data = data.sort_values(['datetime', 'Association'], ascending=[True, False])

_condition_1 = (data.Source == data.Source.shift(-1))
_condition_2 = (data.Association == "associated") & (data.Association.shift(-1) == "disassociated")
new_df = data.copy()
new_df["datetime associated"] = np.where((_condition_1 & _condition_2),data.datetime,np.nan)
new_df["datetime diassociated"] = np.where((_condition_1 & _condition_2),data.datetime.shift(-1),np.nan)
new_df = new_df.dropna()
new_df.drop(['datetime'],axis=1, inplace=True)
display(new_df)
```

Tell me if it answers your question

Comment: TypeError: The DType  could not be promoted by . This means that no common DType exists for the given inputs. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`. The full list of DTypes is: (, )

Comment: Try to replace the 2 np.where lines by : 
new_df["datetime associated"] = np.where((_condition_1 & _condition_2), data.datetime.astype(str), np.nan)
new_df["datetime disassociated"] = np.where((_condition_1 & _condition_2), data.datetime.shift(-1).astype(str), np.nan)